# Ways of using exult in a sentence?

Tags: writing-style, writing-advice

I just discovered what "exult" means, and would like to learn how to use it so it functions properly in a sentence.

For example, is this correct?

> The Catholic Church exulted in its successes.

How else could I use this word in a sentence?

Comment: Any quality dictionary will provide at least one sample usage for each meaning of a word. You can also try a simple web search to find quality publications which use *exult*, e.g. `site:theage.com.au "exult"`. The sentence you've proposed is fine grammatically, but whether or not it makes any sense depends a great deal on context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The Catholic Church exulted in its successes" is a proper sentence.  Exult is also a somewhat archaic word.  I doubt many people talk that way, but you are likely to find it in older texts and from certain academic styles of writing.